# Is it possible to map enum with string values with JAXB2?

Tags: enums, jaxb, schema

Need to have generated enum class like this:

```
public enum FileTypes {
TEXT("txt");
DOC("doc");
ENTERPRISE_ARCHIVE("ear");
}
```

Is it possible to generate enum like this using jaxb?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the typesafeEnumClass binding.

1. Have a naming convention where you give your enums the suffix "Enum".
2. Give each of your xsd:enumeration values (the string value of which is your text description) an xsd:annotation specifiying the Java enum value as follows:

   ```
       <xsd:enumeration value="ear">
           <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:appinfo>
                   <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="ENTERPRISE_ARCHIVE" />
               </xsd:appinfo>
           </xsd:annotation>
       </xsd:enumeration>
   ```
3. Then amend your bindings.xjb file as follows to make all XSD defined types whose name ends with Enum become a Java enumeration with the typesafeEnumClass binding:

   ```
   <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[substring(@name,string-length(@name)-3) = 'Enum']" multiple="true" required="false">
           <typesafeEnumClass />
   </bindings>
   ```